# Payu missing merchant key?Why?

Tags: payumoney

Sending request with parameters required including key to https://test.payu.com/_payment but giving error for missing merchant key.

Comment: Did you find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payumoney has changed the process somewhat so the salt and key from url **https://test.payu.com/_payment** might not work.
Recommendation: Register to new url **https://test.payumoney.com** and use the key and salt. It will work !!